# Implementação da Interface ResponseErrorHandler (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Olá. Estou tentando fazer a sobrescrita da interface ResponseErrorHandler para poder retornar a request inteira (status code, body etc.) em caso de qualquer resposta que não 2xx.

Percebi que o default do Spring (RestTemplate) retorna uma exception em caso de resposta diferente de 2xx. Isso não me ajuda muito.

Seguindo alguns tutoriais, encontrei o seguinte código:

```
@Component
public class LoginErrorHandler
        implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse)
            throws IOException {

        return (
                httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == CLIENT_ERROR
                        || httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse)
            throws IOException {
        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode()
                .series() == SERVER_ERROR) {
            // handle SERVER_ERROR
        } else if (httpResponse.getStatusCode()
                .series() == CLIENT_ERROR) {
            // handle CLIENT_ERROR
        }
    }
```

Mas não entendi como vou conseguir retornar um ResponseEntity sem alterar o retorno do método (que não posso por estar fazendo Override).

Implementação:

```
 //Objeto da requisição
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new LoginErrorHandler());

        //Disparando Request
        return restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
```

Eu retorno a ResponseEntity completa (assim, ele disponibiliza o body, o status code e tudo mais no endpoint)

Gostaria de saber como vocês fazem. Me falaram “bota tudo dentro de um try/catch e boa”, mas isso me parece gambiarra e, mesmo tentando, não deu certo:

```
//Disparando Request
        try {
            return restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            errorCode = e.getRawStatusCode();
        }
        switch (errorCode){
            case 401:
                return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

(não retorna o body da resposta nem nada. É como se a resposta simplesmente não existisse em caso de 4xx ou 5xx!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi generalizar as requests num handler.

```
@Component
@ControllerAdvice
public class RequestErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public void handleError(HttpClientErrorException e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(e.getRawStatusCode(), e.getStatusText());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpServerErrorException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public void handleClientError(HttpServerErrorException e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(e.getRawStatusCode(), e.getStatusText());
    }
}
```